# get value from \tdclock

Tags: macros, number, tdclock

This is my first time asking question here. I'm trying to make an animated `tikzpicture` but to do so, I need the numeric output of `tdclock` package. But after looking around for a couple of days, I'm about to give up.

What I'm looking for is a way to put in a line coordinates the `\tdhour` and `\tdminutes` output.

Something like:

```
\draw (1, \tdminutes/60 + \tdhour) -- (28.7, \tdminutes/60 + \tdhour);
```

But obviously it doesn't work at all, I know :(
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got something working. It works on Foxit but on Acrobat reader it stops after few iterations. Does anyboby know why?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{stuff_fill}=[rectangle,fill=blue!20,minimum size=1.4em]

\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}
 
\OpenAction{/S /JavaScript /JS (%       
    t = new Date();
    tt = t.getSeconds();
    a = this.addAnnot({type: "Line", page: 0, strokeColor: color.blue, points: [[0, tt], [200, tt]]});  
    app.setInterval('a.destroy(); t = new Date(); tt = t.getSeconds(); a = this.addAnnot({type: "Line", page: 0, strokeColor: color.blue, points: [[0, tt], [200, tt]]});',100);
)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (29.7,21.0);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```